# Xmonad and X Window System

Tags: x11, xmonad

I installed *X Window System* (xinit) and `xmonad` only, without installing  a desktop environment.

The problem is that the configuration file `~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs` does not apply after starting.

I usually execute the `startx` command after logging in and then `xmonad` is already running and ignores my `xmonad.hs`. I changed the permissions to 777 for all files under the `~/.xmonad` directory.

How would you fix this?

Comment: Does `xmonad --recompile` work?

Comment: @sr_ Yes, it works.

Comment: @sr_ This even solved it. Please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `xmonad --recompile`.

While I cannot answer why it doesn't automatically recompile if `.xmonad/xmonad.hs` is changed (I think it should and once did), it might help, especially with finding errors in the configuration without restarting the session.